# No id when I add to the database via rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a database and I was able to add a new element with

`Table.new(:name => "test", :path => "test2")`

The problem is that now when I try to add a new element, it does not handle the id. The id is nil and the element is not added to the database. The controller line is:

```
def new
  @memes = Memes.new
end
```

The same happens when I try to add an element via post or get. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table.new won't save to the databse or have an automatic id created. You'll need either:

```
Table.create(:name => "test", :path => "test2")
```

or

```
table = Table.new(:name => "test", :path => "test2")
table.save
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the following message:
Memes.create(:name => "test", :path => "test2")
   (0.3ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "memes" ("created_at", "name", "path", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 10 Jul 2013 17:36:21 UTC +00:00], ["name", "test"], ["path", "test2"], ["updated_at", Wed, 10 Jul 2013 17:36:21 UTC +00:00]]
   (33.8ms)  commit transaction

which seems good, but Memes.all do not show the new element. I have spent hours :-P